# anonymous EventHandler doesn't remove itself

Tags: java, events, javafx, event-handling

I have this following piece of code in a controller class:

```
public void chooseFromBox() {
    for (Node n : myHbox.getChildren()) {
        ScaleTransition transition = new ScaleTransition(Duration.seconds(0.3), n);
        transition.setByX(0.7);
        transition.setByY(0.7);
        transition.setAutoReverse(true);
        transition.setCycleCount(2);
        transition.play();
        n.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                transition.stop();
                int i = myHbox.getChildren().indexOf(event.getSource());
                for (Node n : myHbox.getChildren()) {
                    n.removeEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, this);
                    // This instruction doesn't seem to work
                }
                gui.getNetworkHandler().doSomething(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I need the EventHandler to be gone immediately after one of the children has been clicked. The line with `n.removeHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, this);` gets executed (i can see it from the debug) but after the chooseFromBox() method is done, i can click one of the children again and it will trigger again.

EDIT: after following @Itai suggestion, i changed my code to this:

```
public void chooseFromBox() {
    for (Node n : myHbox.getChildren()) {
        ScaleTransition transition = new ScaleTransition(Duration.seconds(0.3), n);
        transition.setByX(0.7);
        transition.setByY(0.7);
        transition.setAutoReverse(true);
        transition.setCycleCount(2);
        transition.play();
        EventHandler<MouseEvent> handler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                transition.stop();
                int i = myHbox.getChildren().indexOf(event.getSource());
                n.removeEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, this);
                gui.getNetworkHandler().doSomething(i);
            }
        };
        n.setOnMouseClicked(handler);
    }
}
```

I have another similar method, but the same approach doesn't work:

```
void useThing(ActionEvent event) {
    for (Node n : otherHbox.getChildren()) {
        EventHandler<MouseEvent> handler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                int i = otherHbox.getChildren().indexOf(event.getSource());
                for (Node n : otherHbox.getChildren()) {
                    n.removeEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, this);
                }
                gui.getNetworkHandler().doSomethingElse(i);
            }
        };
        n.setOnMouseClicked(handler);
    }
}
```

What am i missing?

Comment: You are trying to remove the `EventHandler` assigned to one node from all the other nodes, but they all have distinct handlers. You would have to either create one handler and assign it to all nodes, or keep references to all handlers.  A different approach altogether would be to not remove the handler, but instead have a flag and check it inside the handler - this way you can set it from anywhere, and the handlers would abort if it is set.

Comment: The problem here is that if one child is clicked, i need to remove the handler for each children. If i were to keep a reference to the handler and give the same one to each children, could i reference it with this or should i use its reference name? The former seems to have the same problem i'm facing now, the latter suffers from a circular reference problem. Unfortunately setting a flag is not an option, i need to remove the handler.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try swapping out this

```
    EventHandler<MouseEvent> handler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            transition.stop();
            int i = myHbox.getChildren().indexOf(event.getSource());
            n.removeEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, this);
            gui.getNetworkHandler().doSomething(i);
        }
    };
    n.setOnMouseClicked(handler);
```

With this

```
    n.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        transition.stop();
        int i = myHbox.getChildren().indexOf(event.getSource());
        //n.removeEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, this);
        n.setOnMouseClicked(Event::consume);
        gui.getNetworkHandler().doSomething(i);
    });
```

Similarly swap this

```
    EventHandler<MouseEvent> handler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            int i = otherHbox.getChildren().indexOf(event.getSource());
            for (Node n : otherHbox.getChildren()) {
                n.removeEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, this);
            }
            gui.getNetworkHandler().doSomethingElse(i);
        }
    };
    n.setOnMouseClicked(handler);
```

with this

```
    n.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        int i = otherHbox.getChildren().indexOf(event.getSource());
        for (Node node : otherHbox.getChildren()) {
            node.setOnMouseClicked(Event::consume);
        }
        gui.getNetworkHandler().doSomethingElse(i);
    });
```

I used consume in my testing to remove the event you may want to change that depending on what else you are doing